# Custom login validation in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my User model I have a status field. I only want to allow users with the status of 'active' to log in. I was thinking of creating a custom Validator in AppServiceProvider but unsure where to use it when the user is logging in.

Can I overwrite the login() or validateLogin() from the AuthenticatesUsers() trait?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the source code of the trait ([you can see it here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L72)) I am seeing:

```
    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }
```

You can pass an array of credentials to the attempt method.

So, all you need to do is to pass a fixed value with the rest of the request data.

Just to make an example, if in this moment you're passing a

```
['email' => 'my@email.com', 'password' => 'my-password']
```

you will now need to pass

```
['email' => 'my@email.com', 'password' => 'my-password', 'status' => 'active']
```

or whatever value you need :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm a bit confused on where to put the array. I used the artisan command to scaffold all the auth routes/controllers. I can only see create() and validate() in the Auth controller but that only relates to registering users?

Comment: You can just rewrite the method you need in your class... in this case, `login`, because your implementation would have the [precedence over the trait one](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) (look to the example #3)

Comment: Yup, thanks. I ended up doing something similar after talking to a colleague. I added the `validateLogin` to my controller and added a custom validator to the username. So I ended up with `$this->loginUsername() => 'required|active'`. Then dropped my custom validator in `AppServiceProvider`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @sjhuda if you've found the answer satisfying mark it :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can override `getCredentials` in your AuthController to not have to make any adjustments to that large `login` method, if you would like.

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password') + ['status' => 'active'];
    // return an array with all the default credentials and adding 'status'
}
```

For adjusting the validation you can override `validateLogin`.

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    // adjust as needed
}
```